# Does $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}=\frac{n^{2} \sin\left ( \frac{1}{n} \right )}{2n+1}$ diverges or converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

$$(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}=\frac{n^{2} \sin\left ( \frac{1}{n} \right )}{2n+1}$$

Determine if the following sequence converges or diverges? İf converges, find its value.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Hi and welcome to MSE. Please use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format the question. Also show us your efforts on the problem to avoid this question being highly downvoted or being closed. See [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question?r=SearchResults) link to know how to ask a good question on this website

Comment: I used limit but i couldn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint.** $\sin \frac{1}{n} \approx \frac{1}{n}$ as $n \to \infty.$

Comment: I know that but it doesn't

Comment: $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^2 \sin \frac{1}{n}}{2n+1}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{2n+1} n \sin \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$ united with the hint makes this clearer?

Comment: I found 1/2. But i don't know if it is true. if the answer is correct must be converging because there is a limit.Also thank you very much for your interest

Comment: It is correct, because the first term of the product tends to $1/2$ and the second tends to $1$ (because of the hint). Yes, convergence means that the limit exists and it is a finite number, divergence means that that the limit is $\infty$ or $-\infty$. You're welcome!